# Python3 open file in folder if it exists or create new file and folder

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to open a file, however if it doesn't exist I'd like to create it.

Is there a quick and easy way to `open("folder/file.txt")` and if file.txt doesn't exist it'll create it, and if folder doesn't exist it'll create both folder and file.txt?

I saw a few forums mention passing variations of w, a, w+, wt ECT in the open function but I still get an error.

been trying with this

```
with open("~/folder/file.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: Dustin, why don't you try it as follows: try to open a file in a non-existing folder where your user has the necessary privileges. Tell us the results :)

Comment: `~` do not expand to home directory in `python`. You should use `os.environ['HOME']` instead of `~`.

Comment: So i tried opening a file that didn't exist inside a folder that does exist with the correct privileges and it successfully created the file. However if the folder doesn't exist as well then i get `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `os.path.expanduser(path)` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)). This will perform the necessary replacement on `~`.